# how to export the data in file using java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, linked-list

I need to export the values in 4 column.values for 3 columns are populating properly.
I am having trouble with 4th column which is organization column.it is multivalued column.i.e.: it has multiple values.

I have tried to convert from object to String for organization column but didnt help.

Please see the code below:

```
    String appname = "abc";
    String path = "//home/exportfile//";
    String filename = path+"ApplicationExport-"+appname+".txt";
    String ret = "false";

    QueryOptions ops = new QueryOptions();
    Filter [] filters = new Filter[1];
    filters[0] = Filter.eq("application.name", appname);
    ops.add(filters);

    List props = new ArrayList();
    props.add("identity.name");

    //Do search
    Iterator it = context.search(Link.class, ops, props);

    //Build file and export header row
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
    out.write("Name,UserName,WorkforceID,organization");
    out.newLine();          

    //Iterate Search Results
    if (it!=null)
    {                               
            while (it.hasNext()) {

                    //Get link and create object
                    Object [] record = it.next();
                    String identityName = (String) record[0];
                    Identity user = (Identity) context.getObject(Identity.class, identityName);

                    //Get Identity attributes for export
                    String workforceid = (String) user.getAttribute("workforceID");                 

                    //Get application attributes for export
                    String userid="";

                    List links = user.getLinks();
                    if (links!=null)
                    {
                            Iterator lit = links.iterator();
                            while (lit.hasNext())
                            {
                                    Link l = lit.next();
                                    String lname = l.getApplicationName();
                                    if (lname.equalsIgnoreCase(appname))
                                    {
                                              userid = (String) l.getAttribute("User Name");
                                              List orgList = l.getAttribute("Organization");

                                    }
                            }
                    }                               

                    //Output file
                    out.write(identityName+","+userid+","+workforceid+","+org);                             
                    out.newLine();                                                                          
                    out.flush();
            }                       
            ret="true";
    }
    //Close file and return
    out.close();
    return ret;
```

The output of this code should be:

for ex:
Name,UserName,WorkforceID,organization
abc,abc,123,xy
qwe,q01,234,xy

any help correcting this code will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

This should give you the output you want:

out.write(identityName+","+userid+","+workforceid+","+Arrays.toString(orgList.toArray());

Comment: Can you guide me where should i put this syntax ?

Comment: You have the line:`out.write(identityName+","+userid+","+workforceid+","+org);` to save out data to the file. I can't find the `org` variable in your example code above. Is `org` supposed to be the string that contains the data from `orgList` ?

Comment: out.write(identityName+","+userid+","+workforceid+","+org);
here i changed to orgList but still i am getting the void value...
how do i use list function and see if there is a toString method...
since the data in organization column is a List

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to declare `List orgList` outside the while loop since everytime it is being created and also you are using org and i havent seen any org elsewhere in your code

Comment: I have declared the List outside the while loop and changed org to orgList.but still it didnt help to get me the output for organization.